# UI element's animation?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to `Windows Phone` development and so I am not very familiar with `Storyboards` and don't know if they would suit me for this situation.

I have a `Canvas` that I place a `Rectangle` on. I want the Rectangle to move off smoothly in a random direction (handled by dealing with a translation and picking x and y) when I call its move method.

I have made a simple Java application before of the game Breakout where I handled the ball's movement by moving it to a location very nearby in a while loop and pausing the while loop by an amount so you could see the animation of the ball's movement in the window. I was wondering if I could do the same in this situation using a while loop since I believe it would be best of what I yet plan to do with my app.

I have tried the following when the Rectangle is tapped:

```
private void TestRectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int x = 1;
    while (x < 50)
    {
         double d = Canvas.GetLeft(TestRectangle);
         Canvas.SetLeft(TestRectangle, d + 1);
         TestCanvas.UpdateLayout();
         System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5).Wait();
         x++;
    }
   /*
    int y = 1;
    while(y < 200)
    {
        dragTranslation.Y += 1;
        TestCanvas.UpdateLayout();
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1).Wait();
        y++;
    }
    * */  
}
```

The thing is that this is not updating quick enough and so I don't get a smooth animation as the rectangle moves, it pretty much jumps to its final location when clicked.

How can I accomplish this because I eventually want to make it so the Rectangle moves randomly around the screen and collides with the edges of the Canvas?

If I have to resort to using a `Storyboard` can someone point me to an example of moving an object along a random path (**Using C# and not XAML**).

Answer (score 0):

XAML and Expression Blend are an easy way to create animations.

Here is the XAML that defines the storyboard and animations.

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Name="MoveRectangleStoryboard"
              Completed='MoveRectangle_Completed'>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="TestRectangle">
      <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                            Value="0"
                            x:Name='xKey1' />
      <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                            Value="165.423"
                            x:Name='xKey2' />

    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="TestRectangle">
      <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                            Value="0"
                            x:Name='yKey1' />
      <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                            Value="68.408"
                            x:Name='yKey2' />

    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

  <Canvas x:Name='MainCanvas'>
    <Rectangle x:Name="TestRectangle"
               Fill='Orange'
               Tapped='rectangle_Tapped'
               Width='60'
               Height='80'
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.0,0.0">
      <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform />
      </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
  </Canvas>
```

**Code**

```
Random ran = new Random();
private void MoveRectangle_Completed(object sender, object e) {
  xKey1.Value = xKey2.Value;
  xKey2.Value = ran.NextDouble() * (MainCanvas.ActualWidth - TestRectangle.ActualWidth);
  yKey1.Value = yKey2.Value;
  yKey2.Value = ran.NextDouble() * (MainCanvas.ActualHeight - TestRectangle.ActualHeight);

}

private void rectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
  MoveRectangleStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I know you asked for C# only, but I find it easy to use Blend to generate the animations, then edit the results in the text editor and code editor.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward animation of the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties of a UIElement in code would look like this:

```
public void MoveElement(
    UIElement element, double offsetX, double offsetY, TimeSpan duration)
{
    var xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = Canvas.GetLeft(element) + offsetX,
        Duration = duration,
    };

    var yAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = Canvas.GetTop(element) + offsetY,
        Duration = duration,
    };

    Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnimation, element);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnimation, "(Canvas.Left)");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnimation, element);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnimation, "(Canvas.Top)");

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(xAnimation);
    storyboard.Children.Add(yAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

You could use it in your Tapped handler like this:

```
private void TestRectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MoveElement(TestRectangle, 50, 50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
}
```

or without naming the Rectangle, like this:

```
private void TestRectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MoveElement((UIElement)sender, 50, 50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I have a couple of questions. When I tried this I get an error saying the type or namespace name DoubleAnimation could not be found and System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard does not contain a definition for 'Children'. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I think I figured it out. Missing reference to Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;

Comment: How can I add to this to make it run indefinitely? I eventually want it to keep moving around until a condition is met and have it check if it is bouncing into the border of the canvas etc (I assume I would check if it is beyond the canvas in the (To = Canvas.GetLeft(element) + offset?)? I tried to but it into a while loop but my application would not open.

Comment: Also repeat behavior will reset the animation when I just want it to keep moving in its direction (change x or y if it hits the wall) until the condition is met? Is it better to set the duration to a long period because I also plan that if the condition is not met after a certain amount of time I want the "game to be over".

Comment: If you want the animation to run until the object "hits the wall", then calculate the moving distance (and duration) relative to the current position before starting the animation. To get notified when the animation has completed, Storyboard has a [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event. Attach an event handler and start another movement there.